# Is circular call between multi contracts possible?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

## Background

I have two contracts A and B, I can do cross-contract call from A to B, or from B to A. But it failed when I try to do cross-contract call like this: A -> B -> A.

## Test code

I developed a contract for test, repo is https://github.com/hthuang996/test/tree/main/ink/flipper.
There are four methods.

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn send_message(&mut self, addr1: AccountId, addr2: AccountId, m: u8) {
    ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call_type(
            ink_env::call::Call::new()
                .callee(addr1)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .transferred_value(0))
        .exec_input(
            // call receive_message
            ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0x3a, 0x6e, 0x96, 0x96]))
            .push_arg(addr2)
            .push_arg(m)
        )
        .returns::<()>()
        .fire().
        unwrap();
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn receive_message(&mut self, addr: AccountId, i: u8) {
    self.message = i;
    ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call_type(
            ink_env::call::Call::new()
                .callee(addr)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .transferred_value(0))
        .exec_input(
            // call receive_message2
            ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0x03, 0x0e, 0x11, 0xd0]))
            .push_arg(i)
        )
        .returns::<()>()
        .fire().
        unwrap();
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn receive_message2(&mut self, i: u8) {
    self.message = i;
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn get_message(& self) -> u8 {
    self.message
}
```

## Test step

Here I use **substrate-contracts-node**.

### Step 1

Build the contract.

### Step 2

Deploy three contracts named A, B, C with the same wasm file.

### Step 3

Call `send_message` of A, params are `B, A, 8`.

### Result

The transaction failed.

But If I change 3 as shown below:
Call `send_message` of A, params are `B, C, 8`.

The transaction was successful, and `get_message` of B, C were both `8`.

## Question

Is there any error in my code, or the circular call between multi contracts is impossible in ink!?

Comment: Here is the further analysis https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/i-found-set-allow-reentry-may-have-some-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "circular" is usually called "reentrant": The control flow enters `A` a second time in the same call stack. This is disallowed by default for [security reasons](https://medium.com/coinmonks/protect-your-solidity-smart-contracts-from-reentrancy-attacks-9972c3af7c21). In order to make your code work you need to explicitly allow it:

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn send_message(&mut self, addr1: AccountId, addr2: AccountId, m: u8) {
    ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call_type(
            ink_env::call::Call::new()
                .callee(addr1)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .transferred_value(0))
        .exec_input(
            // call receive_message
            ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0x3a, 0x6e, 0x96, 0x96]))
            .push_arg(addr2)
            .push_arg(m)
        )
        .call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))
        .returns::<()>()
        .fire().
        unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Great, the transaction was successful after I add the call flag. But the message field of contract A was not set, namely `message` is still 0.

Comment: I met the same problem, and I found maybe the reason is related to the `call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))`. I will express some details in the following.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if we use `call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))` we can make our smart contract be called in the way of cross contract call by itself. Of course this is meaningless, but maybe it's the same reason causes @george huang's problem. The related code is as following:

```rust
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn receive_message(&mut self, addr: AccountId, i: u32) {

            ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(
                    ink_env::call::Call::new()
                        .callee(addr)
                        .gas_limit(0)
                        .transferred_value(0))
                .exec_input(
                    // call `update_message` of contract `addr`
                    ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0x03, 0x2a, 0x6f, 0x29]))
                    .push_arg(i)
                )
                .call_flags(ink_env::CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))
                .returns::<()>()
                .fire().
                unwrap();
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn update_message(&mut self, i: u32) {
            Self::env().emit_event(EventRecv2{
                triggered: true,
            });
            self.message = i;
        }
```

I call `receive_message` but the input parameter `addr` is just the same smart contract, that is, I use `set_allow_reentry(true)` to make my smart contract be able to call itself in a cross-contract call way.

The result is the same as @george huang met, we cannot update the status of the smart contract in `update_message`. I'm sure `update_message` is executed because the event `EventRecv2` is caught.

So is this a bug? Or should we make some special settings to solve this problem?