# I found `set_allow_reentry` may have some problems

Tags: ink

I found that if we use `call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))` we can make our smart contract be called in the cross-contract-call way by itself. Of course this is meaningless, but maybe it's the same reason causes [@george huang's](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/is-circular-call-between-multi-contracts-possible) problem.

The problem is that we cannot update the status of the reentry smart contract.

The related code is as following:

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn receive_message(&mut self, addr: AccountId, i: u32) {

    ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call_type(
            ink_env::call::Call::new()
                .callee(addr)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .transferred_value(0))
        .exec_input(
            // call `update_message` of contract `addr`
            ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0x03, 0x2a, 0x6f, 0x29]))
            .push_arg(i)
        )
        .call_flags(ink_env::CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))
        .returns::<()>()
        .fire().
        unwrap();
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn update_message(&mut self, i: u32) {
    Self::env().emit_event(EventRecv2{
        triggered: true,
    });
    self.message = i;
}
```

I call `receive_message` but the input parameter `addr` is just the same smart contract, that is, I use `set_allow_reentry(true)` to make my smart contract be able to call itself in a cross-contract call way.

The result is the same as [@george huang](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/is-circular-call-between-multi-contracts-possible) met, we cannot update the status of the smart contract in `update_message`. I'm sure `update_message` is executed because the event `EventRecv2` is caught.

So is this a bug? Or should we make some special settings to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to ink!'s storage management(and it is why reentrancy is disallowed by default).

ink! pulls the storage at the beginning of the call execution and pushes it back at the **ending** of the call execution.

If you allow reentrancy, you allow cases where someone interacts with your contract where the state is not updated yet.

Pseudo code:

```
call A::method {
    let state = load state A; // here
    ...
    call B::method {
        let state = load state B;
        ...
        call A::method {
            let state = load state A; // <- It is the same as state above, because it was not flushed yet
            ...
            flush state; // Flushing(pushing) new state of A into storage that will be overridden later in that example
        }
        ...
        flush state; // Flushing state B
    }
    ...
    flush state; // Flushing old state A -> overrides new state A from the middle call.
}
```

You can see that contract A overrides his state in the case of self-call.
If you allow reentrancy, you also need to worry about the storage state. If you want to do a cross-contract call with reentrancy, flush the state before that call and load it after.

Pseudo code:

```
call A::method {
    let state = load state A;
    ...
    flush state; // Flush here
    call B::method {
        ...
    }
    state = load State A; // Load again here
    ...
    flush state;
}
```

To flush/load the state you need to know how to do that via ink!. Or you can use `flush` and `load` functions from [OpenBrush](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/lang/src/traits.rs#L57) of `Flush` trait. You only need to import that trait and you can do `self.flush()` and `self.load()` like here:

```rust
default fn _do_safe_transfer_check(
    &mut self,
    operator: &AccountId,
    from: &AccountId,
    to: &AccountId,
    ids_amounts: &Vec<(Id, Balance)>,
    data: &Vec<u8>,
) -> Result<(), PSP35Error> {
    self.flush();
    let builder = PSP35ReceiverRef::before_received_builder(
        to,
        operator.clone(),
        from.clone(),
        ids_amounts.clone(),
        data.clone(),
    )
    .call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true));
    let result = match builder.fire() {
        Ok(result) => {
            match result {
                Ok(_) => Ok(()),
                Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            match e {
                // `NotCallable` means that the receiver is not a contract.

                // `CalleeTrapped` means that the receiver has no method called `before_received` or it failed inside.
                // First case is expected. Second - not. But we can't tell them apart so it is a positive case for now.
                // https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1002
                EnvError::NotCallable | EnvError::CalleeTrapped => Ok(()),
                _ => {
                    Err(PSP35Error::SafeTransferCheckFailed(String::from(
                        "Error during call to receiver",
                    )))
                }
            }
        }
    };
    self.load();
    result
}
```

BTW, better to not use raw `CallBuilder` for cross-contract calls. If you need a tip you can ask in [OpenBrush element channel](https://matrix.to/#/!utTuYglskDvqRRMQta:matrix.org?via=matrix.org&via=t2bot.io&via=matrix.parity.io).

Comment: Green, instead of the raw `CallBuilder` what do you recommend?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really works. But I solved this problem by copying the `Flush traits` related code into my own project. I met some trouble(compile errors) when using [OpenBrush](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/tree/v2.0.0) as a dependency in my project. Errors are something like this `extern location for openbrush_lang does not exist: /home/dante/dev/rust/polkadot/openbrush-contracts/example/callee/target/rls/debug/deps/libopenbrush_lang-4a96801b3dad8df2.rmeta`

Comment: @HCastano better to use `ContractRef` auto-generated or [wrappers](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts#wrapper-around-traits) from OpenBrush=)

Comment: @ShawnZ Could you post the code of your repo with the branch where you get that error? Or maybe you can write into the element channel with an example of your code and `Cargo.toml`. I want to find the root cause of that issue=)

Comment: Hey @GreenBaneling, I have solved my problem with the help of [official docs](https://docs.openbrush.io/) . Thank you all the same!